# Nginx, Gunicorn, Flask_restful: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, flask-restful

I am building a Flask_restful API using Nginx and Gunicorn. When attempting to retrieve a large json response, I am getting the following error in the Java consuming application:

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: XXX,XXX; received: 65,378)
```

I am assuming the application is running out of memory somewhere, but I am not able to find a memory setting in Gunicorn or Nginx for the response body size. I have found settings related to the request body, which this is not.

How do I set up `Nginx > Gunicorn > Flask` to be able to serve large JSON objects?

Paging the response is not really an option.